# Spell check Ngram for elastic Search not working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have used in my model to include spell check such that if the user inputs data like "Rentaal" then it should fetch the correct data as "Rental"

**document.rb code**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  belongs_to :user

  Document.import force: true


  def self.search(query)
  __elasticsearch__.search({
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: query,
          fields: ['name^10', 'service']
      }
    }
    })
  end


  settings index: { 
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    analysis: {
      analyzer: {
        edge_ngram_analyzer: { type: "custom", tokenizer: "standard", filter: 
          ["lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter", "stop", "kstem" ] },
            }
        },
        filter: {
                  edge_ngram_filter: { type: "edgeNGram", min_gram: "3", max_gram: 
                  "20" } 
      }
    } do
    mapping do
      indexes :name, type: "string", analyzer: "edge_ngram_analyzer"
      indexes :service, type: "string", analyzer: "edge_ngram_analyzer"
    end 
  end
end
```

**search controller code:**

```
def search
  if params[:query].nil?
    @documents = []
  else
    @documents = Document.search params[:query]
  end
end
```

However, if I enter Rentaal or any misspelled word, it does not display anything.
In my console

```
     @documents.results.to_a
```

gives an empty array.

What am I doing wrong here? Let me know if more data is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `fuzziness` in your `multi_match` query:

```
{
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Rentaal",
          "fields": ["name^10", "service"],
          "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

Kstem filter is used for reducing words to their root forms and it does not work as you expected here - it would handle corectly phrases like `Renta` or  `Rent`, but not the misspelling you provided.

You can check how *stemming* works with following query:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty=true' \
  -d '{
  "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
  "text" : ["rentaal"]
}'
```

As a result I see:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "ren"
        },
        {
            "token": "rent"
        },
        {
            "token": "renta"
        },
        {
            "token": "rentaa"
        },
        {
            "token": "rentaal"
        }
    ]
}
```

So typical misspelling will be handled much better with applying fuzziness.

Comment: Sorry so late but I didn't have much time earlier - I updated my answer with explanation why `kstem` is not enough in your case, may be useful in the future.